# Is it possible to have a static port number for asp.net development server?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio

Is there way -I don't know if it can have negative effects, though- to have the development server's port number to stay static?

(The reason is, I do not want to compare whenever I need to check-in my project file so that the port-number will be changed; or if you know other way than making it static, it is very welcome! )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Visual studio

Project ->  Properties

Web tab

under Server panel check 'Use visual studio Development Server' and then 'Specific port'. In the text box aside set your port

Stefano

Comment: This appears to apply only to Web Application projects, not Web Sites.  Is there a way to do this with a standard "Web Site" project?  (If I'm unclear here are the differences... http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/06/ASPNET-Web-Site-versus-Web-Application-Project.aspx)

Comment: I don't use Web Sites, but try to look at this article http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/482/change-default-port-for-the-aspnet-development-server/ maybe it may be useful